# User input not working

Tags: java

```
else if(digit == 2)
{
      System.out.print("Enter the name of artist : ");
      String artist=input.nextLine();  

      System.out.print("Enter the song title : ");
      String song = input.nextLine();

      System.out.print("Enter the number of week :");
      int oldWeek =input.nextInt();

      System.out.print("Enter the new number of week :");
      int newWeek =input.nextInt()
}
```

Hello , I am running a else if loop where if a user enters 2 the following code will run but the problem here seems to be that when it runs it runs 2 `System.out.println` code together . Here is the sample of my output

```
This program will display singles that was Number one on charts 
Enter 1 or 2. 2
Enter the name of artist : Enter the song title :
```

Comment: u need to post all the relevant portions of the code.

Comment: "it runs it runs 2 System.otu.println code together" - How?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Skipping nextLine() after use nextInt()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-use-nextint)?

Comment: I have posted the output in last paragraph as you can see

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you have a `nextInt()` executed before those `nextLine()`. What happens is that  `nextInt()` doesn't consume the new-line character, therefore the next `nextLine()` will consume it. That makes like that `nextLine()` were beign skipped. **[For further information you could see this entry.](http://christprogramming.wordpress.com/2014/01/30/java-common-mistakes-1/)**

One solution would be calling a `nextLine()` after the `nextInt()` in order to consume the new-line character:

```
int number = scanner.nextInt();
scanner.nextLine(); // Just to consume new-line character
...
```

Another solution would be using `nextLine()` to read the integer, and then parsing it with `Integer.parseInt()`:

```
int number = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
...
```

Comment: Hey i tried doing it but still when it reaches to System.out.print("Enter the name of artist : ");
      String artist=input.nextLine();  
it will automatically show same behaviour

Comment: This issue is pretty common, read the link I posted and you will understand why this happens. And maybe you won't need our help anymore.

Comment: Thank you for the link i went through the page and solved my issue